# Strange FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged is not updating streambuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authetication in flutter application.When user signup or login i can see that  FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged is called
but Streambuilder is not updating the widget. I also noticed that sometime  FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged is not even called after user login. But when i reload the screen or rerun the app i can see that user is logged in. Below is my streambuilder code.

```
return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
        if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
          print(userSnapshot.data);
          print('data changed');
          return FutureBuilder(
            future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)),
            builder: (ctx, asyncdata) {
              if (asyncdata.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                print('user has data');
                return UserList();
              } else {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          );
        } else {
          print('load auth screen');
          return AuthScreen();
        }
      },
    );
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do signIn with a **FirebaseAuth** that you don't assign in **onAuthStateChanged**, so you should do like this:

```dart
 _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
///
StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: _auth.onAuthStateChanged,
///
signIn() async {
var result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
}
```

Comment: I tried your way too but its still showing same result.

Comment: do you want do that with provider?

Comment: I have to manually redirect user to after login screen as authStatechanged is called. but streambuilder is not still updating.